# Relating a model to multiple other models in a single relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model `Thing` which can be subclassed by several types of `Thing` like `PointyThing` and `TastyThing`. I have a second model, `Instance` that is related one-to-many to `Thing`s (one `Instance` may be of the type of a single `Thing` but there will be many `Instance`s of a given `Thing`). `Instance`s are then related to a `Player` (each `instance` has one `Player` but a `player` has many `Instance`s) with a backref so that a `Player` can call it's `.inventory` property to see what it owns.

All well and good, but I also have a model `Place`. I would like for `Place`s to own `Instance`s too in the same way that a `Player` owns an `instance`.

Would it be best to create an `Owner` model that is linked against with the `Instance` model and then subclassed to get `Player`s and `Place`s or some hereto unknown method within SQLAlchemy that I don't yet know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `best` solution you are asking for depends on many factors.

Technically, if I look at your example in isolation, this solution looks like a pretty descent **`hack`** which avoids creating another `relationship` table. And if you will never query with polymorphic support, this could fly just fine. However it would still be a hack. Imagine that later you extend your `Player` model with few more sub-classes, and you might start using polymorphic queries, and you will always have to ask yourself `"how will it impact my hack"?`. And even if everything still would work fine (right now I cannot come up with example which would break your logic), you would still need to be careful.
But lets look what is the benefit of this hack? We save on one `relationship` table, but in fact you introduce another table for your `Owner` model (I assume [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/inheritance.html#concrete-table-inheritance)), so what is the gain really?

On the other hand, I am wondering if your `Instance` table should not in fact be a `ternary` relationship? I assume that each instance of the `Thing` is stored in some `Place` and might belong to a `Player`, so it might just be one table that looks like:

```
Instance[
    ID primary_key, 
    Thing_ID (FK) NOT NULL, 
    Place_ID (FK) NOT NULL, 
    Person_ID (FK) NULL
]
```

Note that `Person_ID` is nullable, as I assume the instance of the Thing might not belong to anyone until assigned. But it could be that it is always `NOT NULL` in your case.

*Hope this helps. Would be good to learn which way you decide to go and why.*

Comment: The reason I can't go with a ternary relationship is because a thing can either belong to a place or a person (as in it can either be on the floor or in someone's pocket).

Since each `Thing` will only ever belong to a single `Owner` object at a time, I think I'm going with inheritance. Although there was talk between me and the other developer on this project about including containers (so suddenly `Thing` would be a subclass of `Owner` too) and I think we need to sit down and figure out a full object hierarchy again.

Thank you for your input, it's certainly helped me on to the right track.

Comment: @Drakekin: from what you describe in the comments, it looks like inheritance actually makes sense